# Refreshing controller action in Yii using Cron

Tags: php, yii, console-application, yii-extensions

I would like to implement refreshing functionality in Yii  for calling a particular action repeatedly every 5 mins. I tried Console Application , but its concept is not clear in this particular context ? How can I implement this??

Comment: Can you put an entry in your crontab?

Comment: @LoverOfEvening how to call a controller action in cconsole command?

Comment: I can't see a reason why you may need to call a front end controller action from CConsoleCommand. If you need this action in front end controller (i.e. accessible from browser), then leave it there, put `wget -O - http://example.com/cron/` in the crontab and don't touch the CConsoleCommand. If you **don't** need the action to be accessible from web, then implement all required functionality inside of CConsoleCommand instance and put something like `./yiic myCommand` (with absolute path and maybe with initialised PATH shell variable)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with cron job.

some examples : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Answer (score 0):

*** I would like to implement refreshing functionality in Yii for calling a particular action repeatedly every 5 mins***??!!

for this purpose i dont think you need a crone or something, just use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

for example , loading something to `<div id="topResults"></div>`in every 5 secs

```
setInterval(function()
    {
        $('#topResults').load('<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("controller/action"); ?>');
    },5000);
```

Comment: This will happen at the time when the application is open. How can I implement it without opening the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can set that action URL in crontab
[check wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/91/implementing-cron-jobs-with-yii/)